# Does Flyway have a "database name" placeholder we can use in our SQL migrations?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, flyway

I would like to know if flyway has some kind of predefined placeholders we can use in our SQL migration scripts ?

What I am trying to do is to execute a few commands in the `master` database before switching back to the database the migrations are meant to be run.

My script would look like this :

```
USE master

-- Create things, make a small dynamic SQL string and run it in the context of my DB

${myMigrationDB}..sp_executesql @myDynamicSQL;

USE ${myMigrationDB}

-- Execute something else in the context of the db defined in flyway.url that will use what has been created previously
```

I know I can create my own placeholder that will hold the database name, but it seems to me that I would repeat something that is somehow already available since it's in my config file in `flyway.url`

I also know I could run the second part in a separate migration, but still I need to run that dynamic SQL using `${myMigrationDB}..sp_executesql @myDynamicSQL;`

Answer (score 0):

There is an open feature request for this: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2297